# jaxrs Response status code 0 mockito

Tags: mockito, junit4

why `responsetest.getStatus()` is returning 0 instead of 201 in my code:

```
final Response response = mock(Response.class);
    when(response.getStatus()).thenReturn(201);

    when(builder.post(Entity.entity(myRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)))
            .thenReturn(response);
    Response responsetest =updatedetails("a",
            Details, id, "single", "foo", "foo1");
```

builder is also Mocked using mockito @Mock

Comment: You might want to try (temporarily) changing your second `when` to: `when(builder.post(any()).thenReturn(response);` - to see whether the post argument matches. If that fixes the issue, you can use `argThat()` with a custom matcher to verify the entity if you need to.

Comment: Note that it's org.mockito.Matchers.any() that I was referencing in my comment above.  It's a synonym for Matchers.anyObject().